# Custom Routing in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

*I cannot understan how to do custom routing in codeIgniter 3?*

**e.g** I have controller named *"User"* and it has method named *"article"* which takes one argument *"$id"*.

So my route is: **/user/article/40**

But I want to do something like this : **/news/technology etc**

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try like this

```
$route[‘news’] = “categories/show/3”;
```

here I am assuming that you have a controller `categories` and a method `show` and `3` is parameter

```
$route[‘news/technology’] = “categories/show/10”;
```

here I am assuming that you have a controller `categories` and a method `show` and `10` is parameter. which means you are showing sub category `technology` of a parent category `news`

or you can use slug in database field and map that in your controller.

Thanks

Comment: where is that supposedly be added?

Comment: @user2957058 in `application/config/routes.php`

Answer (score 0):

So Here is my Solution:

In My **Model** File I changed paramater to search for "title" instead of "id" 
so code in model will be

```
->where(['category_name' => $id])
```

And In **view** I changed the url in anchor tag from

```
<?= anchor("user/category/{$article->category_name}",$article->category_name) ?>
```

to

```
<?= anchor("{$article->category_name}",$article->category_name) ?
```

And finally in the **routes.php** file

```
$route['(:any)'] = '/user/category/$1';
```

So Now My **URL** is

```
newsPortal/Technology
```

*It worked perfectly for me. If you want more explanation Please comment below. I think it's pretty straight forward.*

Comment: When you are storing news into database, store [slug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL) in one field (ensure it has unique value in DB). That way you can avoid later problems with spaces, special characters etc. So instead querying DB for title, you would query DB for slug.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do that in future projects.

Comment: You can use CI inbuilt [function](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#url_title) for that.